# animate function using the height of the screen

Tags: javascript, html

This is for my computing class for homework. I have a bunch of random boxes that start at the top in random positions within a given area. The homework was to get them to spread randomly across the top of the screen and then to drop down the height of the screen. I managed the first part, to get them spread across the top of the screen but as for dropping down the height of the screen.. I've had some interesting results that actually made me laugh. Here's my code, I think the problem is in line 62:

```
<head>
<style>

body, html {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.box{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
}

#container{
    position: relative;
    height: 550px;
}

#box1{
    left: 80px;
    top: 0px;
    background: blue;
}

#box2{
    left: 120px;
    top: 200px;
    background: red;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
    <p> score <span id="score">0</span></p>
</div>
<div id = "container">
    <div id = "box1" class = "box"></div>
    <div id = "box2" class = "box"></div>
</div>



<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js">                              <!--Javascript below this line for speed-->
</script>
<script>

nBoxes = 2;
score = 0;

function addBoxes(){

    for(i=nBoxes+1;i<nBoxes+30;i++){

        $('#container').append('<div id="box' + i + '" class="box"></div>');
        $('#box'+i).css('top',-Math.floor(Math.random()*20)).css('left',Math.random()*screen.width);
        $('#box'+i).animate({height: "100%"},3000);
    }
    nBoxes+=30;
    /*$(".box").dblclick(function(){
            console.log($(this).attr("id"));
            $(this).animate({opacity:0.1, marginLeft:"+=150px"
            },5000);
        }
    )*/
    $('.box').click(function(){
        $(this).stop();
        $(this).remove();
        score += 1;
        $('#score').html(score);
        return false;
    }
    )
}
addBoxes();
setInterval(addBoxes,3000);
</script>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

The jsfiddle as requested: http://jsfiddle.net/19f65ycd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not *sure* what it is you were asking to fix, this change will make the boxes actually fall:

```
        $('#box'+i).animate({top: "100%"},3000);
```

This changes the box's position from the top instead of the vertical size of the box, which you did here:

```
        $('#box'+i).animate({height: "100%"},3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I polished it up a bit. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luqo/10an34ge/)

```
var nBoxes = 5;
var score = 0;

function addBoxes(){

for(i=0;i<nBoxes;i++)
    {    
        var randomColor = Math.random().toString(16).substring(2, 8);
        var randomPostion = Math.floor(Math.random() * (600 - 10 + 1)) + 10;
        var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
        iDiv.className = 'box';
        iDiv.style.cssText = 'width: 50px;height: 50px; border: 1px solid black; margin: 2px;';
        iDiv.style.background = '#' + randomColor;
        iDiv.style.left = randomPostion + 'px';
        iDiv.style.position = 'absolute';               
        $('.box').animate({height: "100%"},3000);
        document.getElementById('container').appendChild(iDiv);       
    }
$('.box').click(function()
                {
                    $(this).stop();
                    $(this).remove();
                    score += 1;
                    $('#score').html(score);
                    return false;
                })
}
addBoxes();
setInterval(addBoxes,3000);
```